# How to check if a folder is writable using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, permissions

I am trying to check if a folder is writable so I can prompt an error dialog.

I am trying this:

```cpp
QFileDevice::Permissions permissions_list = QFile( folderName ).permissions();
if ( permissions_list && QFileDevice::WriteUser ) {}
```

But it does not work. It's the same for both writable folders and restricted ones.

Answer (score 11):

use [QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html):

```
QFileInfo my_dir(folderName);

if(my_dir.isDir() && my_dir.isWritable()){
    // Do something
}
```

but pay attention to [this problem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html#platform-specific-issues) if you're on Windows

Comment: I am on Windows and the problem still remains unresolved. Isn't there a working cross-platform solution? The file I'm trying to write is too big to wait for it to be cached in memory for writing and then get the error message. I want the check to be done a priori.

Comment: An dirty option would be to create an empty file, you might use the QTemporaryFile http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtemporaryfile.html which has the advantage of removing itself once closed

Comment: It looks like that writable on windows just means you can change it's name. That's why the Destop folder is readonly but you can still create a file inside (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089598/incorrect-qfileinfo-permissions-for-user-desktop-on-vista-64)

Comment: since nothing "clean" works till now, I will try to set the flag for the NTFS system as @bibi suggested and i will let you know